# Storing data in Redis then fetch that data

Tags: python, mysql, database, excel, redis

I have an Excel file that contains four columns. I want to fetch this data and store it in MySQL. Later on I want fetch the data from here and store in Redis, then run a validation on it. I have already done the importing of data from Excel to Python.

Comment: You haven't asked a question yet.

Answer (score 2):

You have to reshape your 4 column excel data to a 1 column data. 
The redis client for Matlab/GNU Octave is doing this e.g.: https://github.com/markuman/go-redis/wiki/Data-Structure#arrays
Take care that in this example, Matlab/Octave are using Column-Major-Order.
Python is using Row-Major-Order: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order

So you have to save your 4 column X rows data as a row-major-order list in redis as a list (RPUSH).

### example

given this excel sheet

[image: excel example]

using this python3 code

```
    #!/usr/bin/python3
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    """
    Created on Tue Oct 20 23:02:53 2015

    @author: markus
    """

    import pandas as pd
    import redis

    # redis connection
    r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)

    # open the first worksheed
    df  = pd.read_excel('/home/markus/excel.xlsx',0) 

    # read in as a list
    # [[1, 'two', 'python'], ['excel', 'redis', 'action']]
    a   = list(df.T.itertuples()) 
    print("this is a, your excel list")
    print(a)
    for list in a:
        for value in list:
            r.rpush('myexceldata', str(value))

    # read all back to python
    b = r.lrange('myexceldata', '0', '-1')

    print("A1 becomes 0, B1 becomes 3 ...")
    print(b[3].decode('UTF-8'))
```

to save it serialized as a list in redis

```
    127.0.0.1:6379> lrange myexceldata 0 -1
    1) "1"
    2) "two"
    3) "python"
    4) "excel"
    5) "redis"
    6) "action"
```

This is just one way to save a spreadsheet in redis. It always belong on your datastructure and what you're going to do with it.

Comment: how will i import this excel data to redi then?

Comment: Import  every excel cell in a python list. `a[0] = #excelsheet_data (A1), a[1] = #excelsheet_data (A2) ... a[x] = #excelsheet_data(D100)`. Then iterate over `a` and use `RPUSH yourkeyname a[iterator]`

Comment: can you be more clear thanks :)

Comment: I've attached a minimalistic example.